# Flask response should display mongodb last-modified date in ISO format

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7, flask

I'm using flask to create API. My database is mongodb.

When flask response come, the last modified date is coming in the following format.

```
"lastModified": {"$date": 1473929954742}
```

I'm using Pycharm as IDE on the Pycharm Run terminal is showing in the following format

```
"lastModified": {"$date": 1473929954742}
```

In Mongodb shell showing the following format

```
"lastModified" : ISODate("2016-09-15T08:59:14.742Z")
```

How to show the date in the format which contains in Mongodb when flask response come.

I have used the following line inside flask to return the response.

```
return json.dumps(alldata, default=json_util.default)
```

Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert the timestamp to a ISO formatted date, you can use `utcfromtimestamp`.

```
import datetime as dt
timestamp = 1473929954742/1000
print dt.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(timestamp).isoformat()
# '2016-09-15T08:59:14'
```